# close bad file descriptor in child process

Tags: c

Below is the part of my code. I get the error

> **bad file descriptor**

What's wrong with my code? Why can't my child process close the file?

```
int raceme(void* v)
{
    finish = 1;
    sleep(4);

    if ( close(fd3)!=0 )
        perror("close");
    if ( msync(lib_addr+PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE, MS_SYNC)<0 )
        perror("msync");

return 0;
}

int main()
{
    lib_addr = base;
    int sz;

    finish=0;

    sz = sizeof(cstack) / sizeof(cstack[0]);
    cpid = clone(&raceme, (void*) &cstack[sz-16], CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_FS|SIGCHLD, NULL );

//  synchronize threads
    while(!finish);
    fd3 = open(EATFILE, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, 0777);
    ftruncate(fd3, PAGE_SIZE);
//  try to hit the kmalloc race
    mmap(lib_addr+PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, fd3, 0);
    sleep(10);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: is this fd3 global ?

Comment: @kkk Yes, it's global variable.

Comment: @kkk I guess: `open` and `ftruncate` should happen before `clone`. Otherwise, the cloned process is not able to see it.

Comment: would be nice to have a complete example that compiles; there are quite a lot of declarations we do not see in your snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference from [clone man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone)

> If CLONE_FILES is set, the calling process and the child process share the same file descriptor table. Any file descriptor created by the calling process or by the child process is also valid in the other process. Similarly, if one of the processes closes a file descriptor, or changes its associated flags (using the fcntl(2) F_SETFD operation), the other process is also affected.

On the other hand,

> If CLONE_FILES is not set, the child process inherits a copy of all
>   file descriptors opened in the calling process at the time of clone().
>   (The duplicated file descriptors in the child refer to the same open
>   file descriptions (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptors
>   in the calling process.) Subsequent operations that open or close file
>   descriptors, or change file descriptor flags, performed by either the
>   calling process or the child process do not affect the other process.

Answer (score 0):

`clone()` create a **new process** which cannot access anymore to his father data (unless you create a shared memory). So the file descriptor you open (`fd3 = open()`) cannot be seen by the child, thus the value of fd3 remains invalid in the child process, which causes the error.